# Rewrites a URL to another URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a dilemma from one of my colleague regarding redirection via .htaccess.

Below are example formats:

1.)
**Original URL:**

`https://en.example.com/product_info.php/1596-dry-out-standard-set-p-255?osCsid=50cqlnno30m6dcpb45kkooat36`

**Redirect URL:**

`https://en.example.com/products/s-39-ms-1596-dry-out-standard-set`

2.)
**Original URL:**

`https://en.aersampling.com/product_info.php/bottle-ldpe-wide-mouth-p-120?osCsid=50cqlnno30m6dcpb45kkooat36`

**Redirect URL:**

`https://en.aersampling.com/products/pn-385-bottle-ldpe-wide-mouth-1-liter`

I don't know what to do really, please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work - the problem is that the information in the original URL is different from the redirect URL. That is to say, you got data in one that isn't in the other. All rewrite rules can do really is pattern match a URL and move data about to reformat the url.

The best you can do really is something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^product_info.php/(.+)-p-[0-9]+ products/$1? [L]
```

But this misses out information such as `s-39-ms-1` and `pn-385`.

The same is the case if you are actually looking to mask the URLs so that the "redirect" url masks the original one.

The data present in the "redirect" URLs doesn't match the data in the original ones so you really can't do this with pure htaccess.

What you might be able to do is set up method whereby a user sends in a request that you then route to a special script that analyses the url, queries your data store and constructs the new one, pulling the missing information out.

This is easy enough if you do actually want to redirect cause you would then just tell the script to redirect the user but gets messy if you want to mask the URL cause you'd have to go and serve the page directly on the handling script.

Hope this helps.